# Python Pandas: Split DateTimeIndex in two at missing timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DateTimeIndex such as follows: you can see the timestamps are evenly spaced, except in the middle where there is a jump from `'2005-03-11 15:00:00'` to `'2005-03-13 17:30:00'`.

How could I programatically split the DateTimeIndex at point of the missing timestamp and returns 2 DateTimeIndexs ?

```
DateTimeIndex(['2005-03-11 11:00:00', '2005-03-11 11:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 12:00:00', '2005-03-11 12:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 13:00:00', '2005-03-11 13:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 14:00:00', '2005-03-11 14:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 15:00:00', '2005-03-13 17:00:00',
               '2005-03-13 17:30:00', '2005-03-13 18:00:00',
               '2005-03-13 18:30:00', '2005-03-13 19:00:00',
               '2005-03-13 19:30:00', '2005-03-13 20:00:00',
               '2005-03-13 20:30:00', '2005-03-13 21:00:00',
               '2005-03-13 21:30:00', '2005-03-13 22:00:00',
               '2005-03-13 22:30:00', '2005-03-13 23:00:00',
               '2005-03-13 23:30:00', '2005-03-14 00:00:00')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff` to find missing elements in a sequence, and then use `numpy.split` to split at the missing elements:

```
# get the time difference between each timestamp
time_diffs = data.to_series().diff()

# split at each break in the time data
new_data = np.split(data, np.where(time_diffs > np.median(time_diffs)))
```

EDIT: An earlier answer using an explicit loop instead of `numpy.split` and using `numpy.diff` instead of `pandas.series.diff`:

```
time_diffs = np.diff(data)
new_data = []
start_idx = 0

# loop once for each break in the data
for idx in np.where(time_diffs > np.median(time_diffs)):

    # build a new piece at each break in the data
    new_data.append(data[start_idx:idx+1])
    start_idx = idx+1

# add the last piece to the list
new_data.append(data[start_idx:])
```

The above can be run using this as data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DatetimeIndex([
    '2005-03-11 11:00:00', '2005-03-11 11:30:00',
    '2005-03-11 12:00:00', '2005-03-11 12:30:00',
    '2005-03-11 13:00:00', '2005-03-11 13:30:00',
    '2005-03-11 14:00:00', '2005-03-11 14:30:00',
    '2005-03-11 15:00:00', '2005-03-13 17:00:00',
    '2005-03-13 17:30:00', '2005-03-13 18:00:00',
    '2005-03-13 18:30:00', '2005-03-13 19:00:00',
    '2005-03-13 19:30:00', '2005-03-13 20:00:00',
    '2005-03-13 20:30:00', '2005-03-13 21:00:00',
    '2005-03-13 21:30:00', '2005-03-13 22:00:00',
    '2005-03-13 22:30:00', '2005-03-13 23:00:00',
    '2005-03-13 23:30:00', '2005-03-14 00:00:00'
])
```

Comment: I like this solution, this is what I am after. However I receive the error `failed to coerce slice entry of type numpy.ndarray to integer` when trying to use it. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: Found it: I had to change the line `for idx in np.where(time_diffs > np.median(time_diffs))` to `for idx in np.where(time_diffs > np.median(time_diffs))[0]`. Thank a lot, very informative!

Comment: The results of `np.where(time_diffs > np.median(time_diffs))` where in a tuple for some reasons

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You had some syntax errors as well.

```
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2005-03-11 11:00:00', '2005-03-11 11:30:00',
           '2005-03-11 12:00:00', '2005-03-11 12:30:00',
           '2005-03-11 13:00:00', '2005-03-11 13:30:00',
           '2005-03-11 14:00:00', '2005-03-11 14:30:00',
           '2005-03-11 15:00:00', '2005-03-13 17:00:00',
           '2005-03-13 17:30:00', '2005-03-13 18:00:00',
           '2005-03-13 18:30:00', '2005-03-13 19:00:00',
           '2005-03-13 19:30:00', '2005-03-13 20:00:00',
           '2005-03-13 20:30:00', '2005-03-13 21:00:00',
           '2005-03-13 21:30:00', '2005-03-13 22:00:00',
           '2005-03-13 22:30:00', '2005-03-13 23:00:00',
           '2005-03-13 23:30:00', '2005-03-14 00:00:00'])

early = pd.DatetimeIndex(times[:9])
late = pd.DatetimeIndex(times[9:])
```

If you're trying to split a dataframe, try:

```
time_split = '2005-03-11 15:00:00'
early = df.ix[:time_split].index
late = df.ix[time_split:].index
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the differences are consistent until the point at which we split.

```
split = tidx.to_series().diff().diff().abs().idxmax()

t1 = tidx[tidx < split]
t2 = tidx[tidx >= split]

print(split)

2005-03-13 17:00:00

print(t1)

DatetimeIndex(['2005-03-11 11:00:00', '2005-03-11 11:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 12:00:00', '2005-03-11 12:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 13:00:00', '2005-03-11 13:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 14:00:00', '2005-03-11 14:30:00',
               '2005-03-11 15:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

print(t2)

DatetimeIndex(['2005-03-13 17:00:00', '2005-03-13 17:30:00',
               '2005-03-13 18:00:00', '2005-03-13 18:30:00',
               '2005-03-13 19:00:00', '2005-03-13 19:30:00',
               '2005-03-13 20:00:00', '2005-03-13 20:30:00',
               '2005-03-13 21:00:00', '2005-03-13 21:30:00',
               '2005-03-13 22:00:00', '2005-03-13 22:30:00',
               '2005-03-13 23:00:00', '2005-03-13 23:30:00',
               '2005-03-14 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: This is good, however i am after a solution that can split the data in more that 2 pices if there is more than 1 gap. Stephen Rauch below is closer to that I think. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeIndex1=''
DateTimeIndex2=''
for i in DateTimeIndex:
 if '30:00' in i[0]:
  DateTimeIndex1+=i[0]
 else:
  DateTimeIndex2+=i[0]
```

Try The above code, Hope it helps